# how to convert regex from Javascript to work with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, expression

So I was finishing up my last bit of code and noticed PHP was not following the rules set in place with the regular expression. Thought it works just fine with Javascript. I'm not to sure what I need to do to get this working with PHP

```
/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

This is a YouTube validation.

Any tips will be very welcomed.

Edit:

Javascript:

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var ytMatch = ytVideo.value.match(regExp);

  if(ytMatch && ytMatch[2].length == 11) {
```

PHP:

```
$regex  = "/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/";

if(isset($ytVideo) && preg_match($regex,$ytVideo)) {
```

I also just noticed that this regular expression seem to not care if there is a "youtube" inside the URL. I've tried other expressions but none seem to work expect this one... Some what...

Another one that I found that I thought would be a good expression was this one:

```
^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
```

But once again this one doesn't seem to work on either, Javascript/PHP.

Comment: It works the same way as in JS. What is the issue you have? Share the JS and PHP code.

Comment: As Wiktor wrote, regex works the same way in PHP and JS (and actually in most of languages I think).

Answer (score 0):

Simplify:

```
$pattern = "#(http(?:s)?://youtu\.be(/embed)?/[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})|http(?:s)?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11}#";

if(isset($ytVideo) && preg_match($pattern,$ytVideo)) { ...
```

This will match strings that contain (anywhere within them) either something like:

```
http://youtu.be/abcdefghijk 
http://youtu.be/embed/abcdefghijk 
http://youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghijk 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghijk
```

And all their `https` counterparts.

This assumes that the YouTube content ID will be 11 characters long (which seems to be the case for the forseeable future).

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code, you check the length of Group 2, if it is equal to `11`:

```
if(ytMatch && ytMatch[2].length == 11) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In PHP, you  only check if there is a match:

```
if(isset($ytVideo) && preg_match($regex,$ytVideo)) { 
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I would suggest checking with `preg_match` if there is a match, and get the match data into a variable, and then, inside an `if` block, check the second group length:

```
$regex  = "~^.*(youtu\.be/|v/|u/\w/|embed/|watch\?v=|&v=|\?v=)([^#&?]*).*~";
if(isset($ytVideo) && preg_match($regex,$ytVideo, $match)) { 
    if (strlen($match[2]) == 11) {
         // Yes, Group 2 length is 11, do something
    }
}
```

Note you need to escape a `.` in the pattern, and if you use `~` as a regex delimiter in PHP regex, you do not have to escape `/` inside the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that

```
 preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",
"<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>",
$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $out[0][0] . ", " . $out[0][1] . "\n";
echo $out[1][0] . ", " . $out[1][1] . "\n";
```

Comment: I fixed it. With my javascript I noticed that I had ytMatch[2].length with the new expression and that was causing the expression to not work properly and PHP side seem to be working just fine with it. Thanks though for the help.